# C# 2D rotation with matrix

Tags: c#, math, graphics, linear-algebra

I was trying to rotate a simple line counterclockwise. But after the calculations the Y coordinate was always negative. This is my code:

```
double  degree = 0.785;
       // degree = Convert.ToInt32(degree * Math.PI / 180);
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        // Create pen.
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);


        // Create points that define line.
        System.Drawing.Point point1 = new System.Drawing.Point(500, 0);
        System.Drawing.Point point2 = new System.Drawing.Point(500, 100);

        // Draw line to screen.
        g.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);
        blackPen.Dispose();

        //Draw ´new Line

        Vector vector1 = new Vector(point2.X, point2.Y);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(Math.Cos(degree), -Math.Sin(degree), Math.Sin(degree), Math.Cos(degree),0,0);

        Vector result = Vector.Multiply(vector1, matrix1);

        g.DrawLine(redPen,point1.X ,point1.Y,Convert.ToInt32(result.X),Convert.ToInt32(result.Y));
```

Now I use as for the problems with the rotation:

```
double  degree = 45;

matrix.RotateAt(degree, point1.X, point1.Y);
```

Comment: Haven't you forgot to negate one of the `Cos` calculations when building your matrix? Oh no, forget that it's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because there is no such thing as just "rotation". There is only "rotation around the fixed point" and the movement depends on the selection of that "fixed point". What you do now is effectively rotate around `(0,0)` and given that your `X` is `500`, it obviously moves the whole thing up i.e. in the negative `Y` area. Unfortunately it is not quite clear around which point you want to rotate the line but anyway [`Matrix.RotateAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awacs0xh(v=vs.110).aspx) is the method you should look at. So to rotate around one of the ends you may use code like this:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.RotateAt(angleInDegrees, new PointF(point1.X, point1.Y));
```

Also you don't have to make multiplication yourself. Usually it is better to set the [`Graphics.Transform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform(v=vs.110).aspx) directly or using [`Graphics.MultiplyTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt34tx5d(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

One more thing, the line

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
```

is suspicious. If you want to draw something on a `Control`, you should override its [`OnPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.110).aspx) method and then get `Graphics` from the [`PaintEventArgs.Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: I tested it now with a 90° rotation and it was looking just like a 45° rotation. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user19440, are you sure you passed `angleInDegrees` to `RotateAt` rather than in radians?

Comment: @user19440, in that code `degree = 45` so why do you expect rotation to be by `90`? P.S. I hope you start from the identity matrix `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();` as in my code.

Comment: yes I do, this was just an example I actually used degree=90